# Set data to custom field in product not working

Tags: magento2.3

I added a custom field to product module which is getting a multi-select list.
When i'm using SetData to get data added to my table for specified product, it is not working.

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    $product->setData("custom_field", '1,2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    $product->setData("custom_field", '1,2');
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: "$product->save();" it causes the observer to enter into an infinite loop, this solution is wrong !